# docker-compose python: can't open file './main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /proxy-scraper-checker-master

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libc-dev

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /proxy-scraper-checker-master
CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    proxy-app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: proxy-app
```

This is structure of my project dir (from which I run my docker commands):

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
├── proxy-scraper-checker-master
     └── main.py
```

When I run the following command in the above directory:

> docker-compose up

I get the following error message:

```
C:\Projects\myprojects\docker-example>docker-compose up
Creating proxy-app ... done
Attaching to proxy-app
proxy-app    | python: can't open file './main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
proxy-app exited with code 2
```

Could someone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in the lines.

```
COPY . /proxy-scraper-checker-master
CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

You are copying the entire directory into `/proxy-scraper-checker-master`, so then your `main.py` file would be `/proxy-scraper-checker-master/proxy-scraper-checker-master/main.py`.

To debug this, you can enter a bash terminal within the container and look around the directory structure to find `main.py`. `docker-compose` will have built the image, so you can find the image name with `docker images`, or you can rebuild it.

```
jakub@dash:/tmp/so$ docker build --tag my_python .
jakub@dash:/tmp/so$ docker run --rm -it my_python bash
# At this point, we are inside the Docker container.
root@924a7f854119:/proxy-scraper-checker-master# pwd
/proxy-scraper-checker-master
root@924a7f854119:/proxy-scraper-checker-master# ls
Dockerfile  docker-compose.yml  proxy-scraper-checker-master  requirements.txt
root@924a7f854119:/proxy-scraper-checker-master# realpath proxy-scraper-checker-master/main.py 
/proxy-scraper-checker-master/proxy-scraper-checker-master/main.py
```

At this point, we have found the path to `main.py`. To fix the original issue, we can change the `CMD` in the Dockerfile to the following:

```
CMD [ "python", "/proxy-scraper-checker-master/proxy-scraper-checker-master/main.py" ]
```

We can improve the Dockerfile to remove redundant `COPY` instructions. Using the below Dockerfile, the absolute path to `main.py` is `/app/proxy-scraper-checker-master/main.py`. We can reference it with the relative path `proxy-scraper-checker-master/main.py` because we are currently in `/app` (thanks to the `WORKDIR` instruction). We could also reference it with the absolute path.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libc-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "proxy-scraper-checker-master/main.py" ]
```

I recommend reading the [`COPY` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) to understand its behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried both changes and the error still persists

Comment: Shell into your container and see where your `main.py` file is.

Comment: I'm kind of new to docker, how would I do that please, given my container won't even run?

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, and indeed it is. You directed me to the right path to solve my problem, with the bash debugging. I also adapted your suggestions for the Dockerfile configuration, as it makes much more sense, and has less layers. Thanks again!